# Ajuda com consulta criação tarefa agenda

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Galera,

Estou fazendo um script para disparar uma mensagem de acordo com o registro gravado no banco de dados.
É como se fosse uma tarefa CRON.

Tenho o seguinte registro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vou colocar uma pagina PHP na tarefa CRON do Cpanel, mas como posso fazer uma consulta que verifica a cada minuto se o registro está na hora e dia para ser disparado?

Nesse exemplo da imagem, deveria retornar o registro quando:
9 horas 5 minuto segunda, terça ou quinta-feita

Veja que mês e dia está com *

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `agendamento` 
WHERE 1 =1
AND (mes = MONTH(NOW() ))
```

Como poderia verificar o asterisco e não entrar nas condições, vou utilizar operador OR será que funciona?

Comment: Quer que quando no registro tiver * (asterisco) no mês, ele não busque?
Se for isso você pode verificar algo como: AND mes != '*'

Comment: Não é só isso é mais complexo pois precisa verificar todos os campos. Minuto, hora, dia, semana, mes

Comment: Sim, então você deverá ter um (AND) no where para cada condição, um para minuto, hora, dia, semana, ....

Comment: Exemplo: Se estiver asterisco no campo semana quer dizer que deverá executar todos os dias da semana, Se tiver asterismo no campo MES, quer dizer que tem que executar todos os meses. Se estiver 1,3,5 no campo DIA quer dizer que deverá executar somente na Segunda, Quarta e Sexta

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM  agendamento
WHERE 1 =1
AND (
    (mes = MONTH(NOW())
    OR
    (mes = '*')
    )
AND (
    (dia = DAY(NOW())
    OR
    (dia = '*')
)
```

Acredito que esse seja o caminho que será necessário trilhar, embora eu julgue que será muito mais interessante ter diversas Crons...